# Как программно включить/отключить usb порты?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Как программно включить/отключить usb порты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работая с реестром Windows.

Выключить

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", "Start", 4, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

---

Включить

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR", "Start", 3, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Comment: @uzumaxy А как отключить определенный порт?